# Sources моего сайта,

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Не понимаю, что за папки подключаются к сайту, который я делаю? Эти скрипты я не прописывал и зачем загружаются - не ясно, что делают - не понятно. Нужны ли мне? Наверное, нет. Почему я должен загружать дополнительные 60 тысяч символов - не ясно.
Вот, посмотрите:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зеленые это те, что я подключаю (или использую), а остальные - нет. Зачем эти скрипты нужны?
Вот [сайт](https://vostoksisters.github.io/).

Comment: Если смогли бы загрузить ваш сайт на хостинг и дать нам ссылку, сможем более конкретно помочь в данной ситуации

Comment: @Arsen, обновил вопрос. Скриншот я делал с локалки, а сайт на гитхабе расположен. Возможно, в этом дело?...

Comment: У вас эти скрипты явно подключены в макете страницы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, скриншот, пожалуйста. Потому что я могу дать репозиторий на гитхабе, где вы этих строк никогда не увидите.

Comment: @VostokSisters вообще-то, я их именно там и нашел!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, дай ссылку, пожалуйста, с якорем на строку кода в документе странцицы на гитхабе. Там так можно.

Comment: @VostokSisters на гитхабе есть поиск по репозиторию. Вбейте указанные вами адреса в этот поиск, и он вам всё покажет. У вас эти скрипты явно подключены и присутствуют в репозитории.

Comment: @andreymal, это чушь. Я знаю каждый файл в этом репозетории, а также каждую строчку, которую писал в каждом из них. Вот поиск, [пожалуйста](http://joxi.ru/YmEp8dKF0wE4ar). Кинь ссылку или скриншот того, где эти строчки в файлах, если не трудно. Пока что я думаю, что ты мне голову морочишь. Я там не вижу ни одного скрипта, о которых я говорил (и ты видишь, я уверен).

Comment: Хм, я невнимательно прочитал вопрос.

Comment: Да, я всё попутал и в репозитории этого правда нет, прошу прощения за мою грубость

Comment: Всё левое (по-настоящему левое теперь) у меня не загружается, так что наверно дело действительно в расширениях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю у вас с сайтом проблем нет, проверил на 'чистом' окне, загружаются только ваши файлы  [ТЫЦ](http://prnt.sc/dzphxx) , по всей вероятности у вас в Source браузер также показывает включения Browser extension, у меня появился код из браузера [ТЫЦ 2](http://prnt.sc/dzpk74) посмотри - Wappalayzer - это расширение браузера, думаю у тебя тоже самое, так что пока беспокоиться нечего ))

Comment: А-а-а, возможно, да. Скорее всего. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

siteheart - эти скрипты подгружаются для вашего онлайн-консультанта
Об остальных погуглите. Возможно это сервисы, которые используются на сайте.

Comment: Какого онлайн-консультата?  Я не подключал никакого консультанта.

Comment: siteheart - популярный чат для онлайн-консультаций на сайте. Часто его вижу. http://www.siteheart.com/ Если не используете - смело удаляйте

Comment: Погуглил насчет амазона (собственно, так и думал), это дата-сторедж, известное хранилище данных. Клево. Зачем, почему, кому нужно - не понятно. Вопрос остается.

Comment: Ну я понял, что siteheart - чат и всё такое. Какого черта он забыл в моем коде и на моем сайте?

Comment: Спросите того кто разрабатывал ваш сайт или того у кого есть доступ к коду. Кстати, насколько мне известно скрипты к сайту можно подключать с помощью Google Tag Manager